# Dúvida nesse código em JS onde deveria ter um link para um json encode

Tags: javascript, jquery, apk

```
$(function() {
    $("#homepage").addClass("visible")
});
//aqui tem uma rota de json encode https://vizer.gratis/wp-json/moble
var siteUrl = "https://vizer.gratis/wp-json/moble";
$(document).on("click", ".gender .button", function() {
    $(".gender .button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".gender input").val($(this).attr("data-val"))
});

function showError(error) {
    $("body").append("<div class='errormsg'>" + error + "</div>");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".errormsg").remove()
    }, 7500)
}

function showSuccess(success) {
    $("body").append("<div class='successmsg'>" + success + "</div>");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".successmsg").remove()
    }, 7500)
}

function showLogin() {
    $("#login").addClass("visible");
    $("#register").removeClass("visible");
    $("#recorve").removeClass("visible");
    $("#homepage").addClass("login");
    $(".homeBtns").hide()
}

function showRegister() {
    $("#login").removeClass("visible");
    $("#recorve").removeClass("visible");
    $("#register").addClass("visible");
    $("#homepage").addClass("login");
    $(".homeBtns").hide()
}

function showRecorver() {
    $("#login").removeClass("visible");
    $("#register").removeClass("visible");
    $("#recorve").addClass("visible");
    $("#homepage").addClass("login");
    $(".homeBtns").hide()
}

function showVoltar() {
    $("#login").removeClass("visible");
    $("#register").removeClass("visible");
    $("#recorve").removeClass("visible");
    $("#homepage").removeClass("login");
    $(".homeBtns").removeAttr('style')
}

function runLogin() {
    var email = $('#login input[name="email"]').val();
    var password = $('#login input[name="pw"]').val();
    if (email, password) {
        $(".pulseLoading").addClass("visible");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:siteUrl+'login/',
                data: {

                    user: email,
                    pass: password
                },
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {

                    $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");

                    if (data.success == "true") {

                        Android.saveUserData(data.userid, data.username, data.email, data.token, data.rank)

                    }else if (data.status == "maintenance") {

                        showError('Nosso servidor está em manutenção!')

                    } else {
                        showError(data.response)
                    }

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");
                    showError('Error Não foi Possível se comunicar com nosso Servidor.')
                }

            })
        }, 500)
    } else {
        showError("Formulário não está completo, verifique e tente novamente.")
    }
}

function runRegister() {
    var email    = $('#register input[name="email"]').val();
    var username = $('#register input[name="username"]').val();
    var pw       = $('#register input[name="pw"]').val();
    var pwv      = $('#register input[name="pwv"]').val();
    var gender   = $('#register input[name="gender"]').val();
    if (!email) {
        showError("Insira o seu email");
        return !1
    }
    if (!username) {
        showError("Insira o seu nome de usuário");
        return !1
    }
    if (!pw || !pwv) {
        showError("Insira as senhas");
        return !1
    }
    if (pw != pwv) {
        showError("Senhas diferentes, introduza novamente.");
        $('#register input[name="pw"],#register input[name="pwv"]').val("");
        return !1
    }
    if (gender == 0) {
        showError("Não escolheu o género, transexual não é permitido, se decida.");
        return !1
    }
    if (email, username, pw, gender) {
        $(".pulseLoading").addClass("visible");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:siteUrl+'register/',
                data: {

                 email    : email,
                 username : username,
                 gender   : gender,
                 password : pw
             },
             cache: true,
             success: function (data) {

                $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");

                if (data.success == "true") {
                    $('#login input[name="email"]').val(email);
                    $('#login input[name="pw"]').val(pw);
                    runLogin()
                }else if (data.status == "maintenance") {

                    showError('Nosso servidor está em manutenção!')

                } else {
                    showError(data.response)
                }

            },
            error: function (response) {
                $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");
                showError('Error Não foi Possível se comunicar com nosso Servidor.')
            }

        })
        }, 500)
    } else {
        showError("Formulário não está completo, verifique e tente novamente.");
        return !1
    }
}

function runReset() {
    var email = $('#recorve input[name="email"]').val();

    if (email) {
        $(".pulseLoading").addClass("visible");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:siteUrl+'reset/',
                data: {
                    email: email,
                },
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {

                    $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");

                    if (data.success == "true") {

                        showSuccess(data.response);

                    }else if (data.status == "maintenance") {

                        showError('Nosso servidor está em manutenção!')

                    } else {
                        showError(data.response)
                    }

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $(".pulseLoading").removeClass("visible");
                    showError('Error Não foi Possível se comunicar com nosso Servidor.')
                }

            })
        }, 500)
    } else {
        showError("Formulário não está completo, verifique e tente novamente.")
    }
}

function showAcesse(){

    Android.saveUserData('0', 'Visitante', 'vizer@vizer.gratis', '0000', 0)

}`
```

**Como devo proceder no meu site para por esse json?`**

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida e onde está o erro?

Comment: nas linhas 4 e 5, tem um link pra um encode, como fazer?

Comment: Sua pergunta ainda não está muito clara, você deseja saber como capturar o JSON daquele link? Ou quer saber aonde no código o mesmo já é utilizado para pegar um JSON?